# When downloading a large file with c#, the file is corrupted

Tags: c#, file, download

I have no problems with files under 200 MB, but when I download a large file, the hash values ​​are corrupted.

That's why I try to download large files by dividing them into parts, but at the end of the work, the hash values ​​are corrupted again.

Is there any other way for this or what am I doing wrong in the code below

```
void getdownload(string url, string fileName, string destinationPath, long totalSize)
{
    List<Tuple<string, string, long>> parts = new List<Tuple<string, string, long>>();
    long partSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024; // 100MB
    int partCount = (int)(totalSize / partSize);
    if (totalSize % partSize > 0)
        partCount++;

    for (int i = 0; i < partCount; i++)
    {
        long start = i * partSize;
        long end = (i + 1) * partSize - 1;
        if (end > totalSize)
            end = totalSize;

        string partFileName = string.Format("{0}.part{1}", fileName, i);
        string partFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, partFileName);
        string urlx = string.Format("{0}?start={1}&end={2}", url, start, end);
        parts.Add(new Tuple<string, string, long>(urlx, partFilePath, end));
    }

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        int currentPart = 0;
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            var totalSize = e.TotalBytesToReceive;
            DownloadChanged(e, parts[0].Item3);
        };
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error while downloading part {0}: {1}", currentPart, e.Error.Message);
            }
            else if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Download of part {0} was cancelled", currentPart);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Part {0} was downloaded successfully", currentPart);
                MessageBox.Show(currentPart.ToString());
                currentPart++;
                if (currentPart < parts.Count)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(currentPart.ToString());
                    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(parts[currentPart].Item1), parts[0].Item2);
                    client.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadFileCompleted;
                }
            }
        };
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(parts[0].Item1), parts[0].Item2);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadFileCompleted;
        MessageBox.Show(parts[0].Item1.ToString());
    }
}
```

I tried fixing my download speed. I said the file on the server might be corrupted, but every time I faced the same problem, the file on the server is intact.

Comment: You could explore your code by creating your own REST API endpoint that behaves the same way as the one you are calling and having it serve a much smaller file consisting of a predictable pattern like all the letters in the alphabet repeating, and set your partition size appropriately smaller. Running your code against that endpoint and opening the parts in a text editor may shed light and if not, debugging is much simpler with a small test file.

Comment: Is this the full code?  I'm guessing not (there's no definition of `DownloadChanged` or `DownloadFileCompleted`).  It looks like you're downloading each part sequentially into the same file (the line: `client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(parts[currentPart].Item1), parts[0].Item2);`)

Answer (score 1):

There could be Couple of reasons:

As you explained above the file might be getting corrupted during the writing process to the disk. This can happen if there are errors or interruptions while writing the file to the disk.

The code is writing multiple parts of the file to the same file, which can lead to corrupted file as the parts are not being concatenated together in a correct way.

The DownloadFileCompleted event is being added multiple times and that could cause issues with the download process.

Comment: I download the file from google chrome and compare it with the hash values ​​on the server, it shows differently again, is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Then perhaps the server is not encoding the file correctly. I would examine the raw http headers, and create some test files with raw byte values, to see if there is some strange text encoding problem.

Comment: yes it's a good idea but when my friends try the program they don't have a problem the problem is my connection speed and there must be a way to get around it

Comment: If the file is served over https and the download from chrome is the same length, then the problem must be somewhere in the network or server. Otherwise you should check if the server supports `Content-Range` to resume downloads from where you left off.